# Process killing itself

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm working on writing a program to batch convert video files using HandbrakeCLI as the converter. I've got most of it set up and am actually working on passing the file to Handbrake now. I create a new process with the location of HandbrakeCLI and pass the arguments. I also make it so it executes in the same shell. It spins up and then starts to go through the converting and gets to three frames or so and kills itself. I'm using Visual Studio 12 on Windows 8 64 bit. Here's my code:

```
static void EncodeVideos()
    {
        var continueConverting = true;

        while (continueConverting)
        {
            var converted = 0;
            if (settings.Optimize == true)
            {
                videos = videos.OrderBy(x => x.InputSize).ToList();
            }

            foreach (var v in videos)
            {
                if (!v.AlreadyConverted())
                {
                    v.CreateOutputPath();
                    var input = String.Format("-i \"{0}\" ", v.InputPath);
                    var output = String.Format("-o \"{0}\" ", v.OutputPath);
                    var preset = String.Format("-Z {0}", settings.Preset);
                    var convertString = String.Format(" {0} {1} {2}", input, output, preset);
                    //Converting is not working correctly yet.
                    var p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(settings.HandBrakeLocation, convertString)
                    {
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                    };
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                    converted++;
                }
            }

            if (settings.Loop == true)
            {
                if (converted == 0)
                {
                    continueConverting = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                continueConverting = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you would like more context for the code, I've put it all on github and you can find it on [Github](https://github.com/Rumel/Freezing-Ironman).

Edit: Fixed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (settings.Loop == true)
            {
                if (converted == 0)
                {
                    continueConverting = false;
                }
                continueConverting = false;
            }
            else
            {
                continueConverting = false;
            }
```

I guess you REALLY don't want to continue converting!

This looks like it's incorrect for a start.

Comment: it doesn't look like the problem - see the loop first, you get to this point only on successful conversion of all videos

Comment: That's in my while loop after iterating over all the videos. That setting is for if a user wants to run conversions, then at the end see if there are new files in the directory and if set to true will loop over them. Otherwise files are just ran over once and the program exits.

Comment: You are right though, I forgot to to have the second continue converting outside the if be set to true. I'll have to go fix that.